# Finding the value of an XML node in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, e4x

Why is @assigned always 0?

```
var gates:XML = <gates>
    <gate_id>
      10991
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      10999
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      11000
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      11001
    </gate_id>
  </gates>;

var assignedGateIds:Array = ["10991","10999"];

for each(var xgate:XML in gates..gate_id){
    var gateId:String = xgate.text();

    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(xgate.text())>-1){
        xgate.@assigned = 1;
    }else{
        xgate.@assigned = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a trace for xgate.text() to see what comes back.

Comment: 10991
10999
11000
11001

Answer (score 0):

Quirte simple, because the text() function doesn't return a string but an Object. Whe you use trace, it gets converted to a string, but if you check with `trace(getQualifiedSuperclassName(xgate.text()));` you'll see it returns an Object.

to get around this I usually use 
`trace(getQualifiedSuperclassName(xgate.text()+''));` and force it to a string, you can also use `as String`

```
var gates:XML = <gates>
    <gate_id>
      10991
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      10999
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      11000
    </gate_id>
    <gate_id>
      11001
    </gate_id>
  </gates>;

var assignedGateIds:Array = ["10991","10999"];

for each(var xgate:XML in gates..gate_id){
    var gateId:String = xgate.text();

    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(xgate.text()+"")>-1){ // <- added +'' here
        xgate.@assigned = 1;
    }else{
        xgate.@assigned = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(xgate.text())>-1){
```

To

```
    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(gateId)>-1){
```

Or To

```
    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(String(xgate.text()))>-1){
```

Or To

```
    if(assignedGateIds.indexOf(xgate.text().toString())>-1){
```